# Database initialization in asp.net mvc core 2

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have created a very basic web application with asp.net mvc core 2.

This application works with a Database and entity framework core. I have worked with Migration and Code First stragegy.

Everything works fine.

I can create the database with command:

```
$ dotnet ef database update
```

What i want to do at this time is to create some data in the database (from C# code).

I have read some tutorials and i created a DataInitializer class which contains code that will create my data.

I have put this line at the end of Startup.cs Configure method:

```
    DataInitializer dataseed = new DataInitializer();
    dataseed.InitializeDataAsync(app.ApplicationServices);
```

The problem is that data is inserted each time i run my application.

I do not want to check by C# code if data is even in the database because it is very dangerous.

What i want to do is to trigger data initialization with migration. Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is the format I use for running seed data into a fresh table it works only runs 1 time per table assuming no data in that table.

```
 //run migrations 
_context.Database.Migrate();

if(!_context.SomeTable.Any()){
   //foreach 
     //insert
  _context.SaveChanges();
}
```